# i need an answer please : bootstrap 3 this is for a job applyment?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, clearfix

In order to get a job , the recruitement ask me to solve this problem in order to get the job !
Here the html of the question :

```
<div id="header" class="col-md-12">header</div>


    <div id="content" class="col-md-12 clearfix">
        <img src="1.jpg" class="changeme">
        <img src="2.jpg" class="changeme">
    </div>

<div id="footer" class="col-md-12">footer</div>
```

Here the CSS of the question  :

```
#header,
       #footer{
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            background: red;
            text-align: center;
        }

        body img{
            float:left;
        }
        body img:nth-child(2n){
            float: right;
        }`
```

use of bootstrap 3.7.0.

I must only use a class!

See the the problem here :
[The jsFiddle of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/5704w27n/)

Comment: If this is for a job interview you should probably research the answer yourself instead of outsource it. You also haven't actually stated what the issue is

Comment: And what is the question ?

Comment: Not to be harsh but, you don't deserve to have the job if you're like that. What happens if they took you in and gave you a task that you don't know? You'll post again that you can't do it?

Comment: it would be bad if you dont do it yourself right?what if you encounter same problem when you are hired you will come to ask us to solve it again for you?piece of advice do it yourself if you get stuck ask for help from here

Comment: I'm still a student and it's my first job applyment :/

Comment: btw... what did they ask you to do? Anyway this is not a "write code on my behalf" service site so I doubt anyone will ever answer.

Comment: i swear i spent the hole night looking for an answer but i only get to add a class="pull-left" to the second img then the emojey is completed

Comment: We still don't have the problem ...

Do you have to complete the image on the left ? right ? center ? ...

Comment: the company just post on linkedIn "we need a front-end developer 
,solve this enigme using Class***:;"

Comment: @GrégoireFruleux : i'm also confused like you are in addition i'm a little bit stressed because if i get this job i'll be able to complete my master degree :/

Comment: Then I guess it's part of the enigma ! Good luck for your degree and this tests !

Comment: Thanks a lot , people starts blaming me but i just needed to check if my answer is right   ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the result my self just for fun ,here the solution:

```
body img {
    float: left;  
}
body img:nth-child(2n) {
   float: right;
}

#content{display:flex;text-align:center;width:100%}

.changeme1{
   margin-left:auto;float:none;
}
.changeme2{
   margin-right:auto;float:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5704w27n/54/). 
You want this to happend only by adding a class so there it is. In the second image add the class `pull-left` and this is fixed.

```
  <div id="header" class="col-md-12">Header</div>
     <div id="content" class="col-md-12 clearfix">
       <img class="changeme " src="http://uteek.net/test/1.jpg">
       <img class="changeme pull-left" src="http://uteek.net/test/2.jpg">
     </div>
  <div id="footer" class="col-md-12">Footer</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help i really appreciate that ,but i already do that i don't know if this the right answer i only have one chance to submit my answer and i really need this job !

Comment: Does this fixed your problem ?

Comment: Thanks for help i really appreciate that , but i already did that i don't know if this the right answer because the emojey is completed but it slides to the left Like i mentioned in the previous comment ,i only have one chance to submit my answer and i really need this job !

Comment: But what you exactly want to archive ?

Comment: i thought they want me to assemble the two images and then center them ,i'm i wrong ?

Comment: I think that they want only to get those two images to complete only one image because this is the only thing you can archive by adding only one bootstrap class

Comment: do you think i must post my answer just by adding the pull-left to the second img ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, i think i'll post this answer ,i really appreciate your help ! ^^

Comment: they responded me  saying that i was too close but not right :/

Comment: They can't just say you are wrong because you have fixed that only by using a class in bootstrap so if there are many ways you have fixed in your way so just write to them again

Comment: And i don't know why you removed the correct answer tick ?

Comment: because it wasn't the right answer he says that i must center the images .. don't take it negatively i just want to know the good answer because i'm really disappointed

Answer (score 0):

Change the class in the img tags to:

```
 <img class="pull-left" src="http://uteek.net/test/1.jpg">
<img class="pull-left" src="http://uteek.net/test/2.jpg">
```

if this is what it needs
or you can just change the bottom img tag

Comment: Thanks for help i really appreciate that ,
but i already did that i don't know if this the right answer because the emojey is completed but it slides to the left 
Like i mentioned in the previous comment ,i only have one chance to submit my answer and i really need this job !